# Add random number prefix to uploaded image

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to add a 3 digit random number at the front of the uploaded image

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])!=""){
  $name=$_FILES['photo']['name'];
  $size=$_FILES['photo']['size'];
  $type=$_FILES['photo']['type'];
  $temp=$_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];
  $random = rand(000,999);
  $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

  move_uploaded_file($temp,"files/".$name);

$query=$DBcon->query("INSERT INTO upload (name,date) VALUES ('$name','$date')");
    if($query){
        header("location:index.php");
    }
    else{
        die(mysql_error());
    }
}
```

Comment: "478" seems pretty random to me.  Just add that to the front of each name.

Comment: you have `$random` but for some reason do nothing with it?

Comment: I have used the 'id' number of the post as prefix for the images. ID is by default an unique number. And this way I can easily tell where the image belongs. To what post.

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wanted to use a **3 digit** random number at the front of the file name. For generating the random number you have used :

`$random = rand(000,999);`

The above statement will generate random numbers between `0` and `999`, which means not all generated random number will be **3 digits**.

You need to pad the random number with `0` to the desired length.

```
$random = rand(000,999);
$random = str_pad($random, 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

To use this random number in your file name, prepend it to the filename as below.

`$name = $random.$name;`

Your completed code should look like this.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])!=""){
  $name=$_FILES['photo']['name'];
  $size=$_FILES['photo']['size'];
  $type=$_FILES['photo']['type'];
  $temp=$_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];
  $random = rand(000,999);
  $random = str_pad($random, 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
  $name = $random.$name;
  $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

  move_uploaded_file($temp,"files/".$name);

$query=$DBcon->query("INSERT INTO upload (name,date) VALUES ('$name','$date')");
    if($query){
        header("location:index.php");
    }
    else{
        die(mysql_error());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
move_uploaded_file($temp,"files/".$name);
```

do this:

```
move_uploaded_file($temp,"files/".$name.$random);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])!=""){
  $name=$_FILES['photo']['name'];
  $size=$_FILES['photo']['size'];
  $type=$_FILES['photo']['type'];
  $temp=$_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];
  $random = rand(000,999);
  $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$name=$random.$name;
  move_uploaded_file($temp,"files/".$name);

$query=$DBcon->query("INSERT INTO upload (name,date) VALUES ('$name','$date')");
    if($query){
        header("location:index.php");
    }
    else{
        die(mysql_error());
    }
}
```